# UILocalNotification repeatInterval keeps pushing notifications

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uilocalnotification

When using repeatInteval the notifications keep being pushed one after the other regardless if set on Minutes/Day/Hour etc.

It did seem to work fine until I tested every few seconds now settings won't change back. Any reason why ?

```
    var dateComp:NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComp.year = 2015;
    dateComp.month = 06;
    dateComp.day = 03;
    dateComp.hour = 15;
    dateComp.minute = 27;
    dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    var calender:NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    var date:NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.category = "Daily"
    notification.alertBody = "OK"
    notification.fireDate = date
    notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitDay
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: dateComp.year = 201; ???

Comment: Typo error, changed it back (and set it to 2020) but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the notification to be repeated with CalendarUnitDay it should repeat each day at the same time after the first fire. 
Pay attention that to delete scheduled notification is not sufficient to delete the app (at least it was in iOS7) because the system keeps the notification registered but silent for 24h to avoid accidental uninstall.
Maybe you are still seeing old scheduled notifications.
To be sure put a breakpoint and ask the app delegate for its `-scheduledNotifications` if you find more than you expected this is the source of your problems.

Comment: Thanks, that explains why the application sends out notifications as soon as it is reinstalled. How do I ask the delegate for the scheduled notifications ? (Sorry am new to iOS development)

Comment: In - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: put a breakpoint and in the debugger write po UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications()

Answer (score 0):

If you tested with every few seconds just once means that all notifications are scheduled and will be received. Try cancel all the scheduled notifications first and then reschedule at desired time interval

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

Comment: Thanks ! But where should I call the method ?

Comment: Anywhere in you app, for example on viewDidLoad of your rootController. But once you call it delete this line otherwise you will never receive notifications

Comment: If I cancel right after the view controller it deletes all notifications in the notification centre. If I call the method after the notification code then it stops any executions. But still am struggling to change from seconds to minutes/daily @zellb